Check how many Numbers have a decimal part > 0 in Excel
I have a large Excel table where there is a column with values as:
  E         G
person    income
------    -------
joe        100.00
frank       99.00
....

I believe all these rows got just values with .00 as decimal part. However, I need to prove it. I know that there is the function COUNTIFS that I could use to check how many numbers are > 0:
= COUNTIFS(G3:G101723, ">" & 0)

For my problem I need to test how many numbers from column G satisfy:  G - TRUNC(G) > 0
for values in the rank  G3:G101723
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Give a try to the following formula-
=SUM(--(MOD(G2:G7,1)>0))

If you are not a user of Microsoft-365 then confirm the formula to enter by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

